# iPhone 4S OSX 7.1.2 Wifi switch greyed-out (disable)

Tags: ios, wifi

Apple sent a replacement 4S last month: I have used the wifi w/o problems until today.

I have tried:

1) Rebooting the device several

2) Bouncing airplane mode

Questions:

A) Are there any settings (other than airplane mode) that will disable wifi?

B) Are there any diagnostic procedure that can ID root cause of wifi disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Wifi switch is being displayed as greyed out that means that there is a hardware problem with the Wifi modem in the device. I had faced this with my device and Apple replaced it under warranty, I would suggest take the device to an Apple store and they should replace the device as you get 3 months support on replaced devices even if it was a paid replacement.

P.S: Rebooting, Resetting or any other changes can not fix this issue as it is a hardware issue, the earlier you go to the Apple support the better.

Comment: Confirmed it was a hardware problem with Apple